# String interpolation and concatenation for Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to setup a Jenkinsfile that gets a job to call other jobs, based on the parameters passed into itself.

Instead of having multiple `when` conditions, I'm thinking that it would be smarter (and manageable for future scaling) if the names of the jobs being called would ideally be concatenating a common prefix with the parameter being passed in, for example:

- CICD_api-gateway
- CICD_front-end
- CICD_customer-service

I'm having difficulty mixing string interpolation with string concatenation to achieve this:

```
    build job: 'CICD_"${params.SERVICE_NAME}"', wait : false
```

In Linux, we are able to use `eval` to achieve this. I'm not sure what the equivalent is in Jenkinsfile syntax.

The full code below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters { string(name: 'SERVICE_NAME', defaultValue: '', description: 'Service being deployed.') }

    stages {
        stage('Build Trigger'){
            steps{
                echo "CICD_${params.SERVICE_NAME}"
                build job: 'CICD_"${params.SERVICE_NAME}"', wait : false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to be a Gstring from the beginning, no need for the single quotes:

```
build job: "CICD_${params.SERVICE_NAME}", wait : false
```